# How to use Servlet ResultSet in jsp page?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I am new in JSP Servlet, the task i want to do is just using ResultSet data of servlet in JSP page... when i runs the code it is giving me errors like

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 148 in the jsp file: /products.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
symbol:   class ResultSet
location: class org.apache.jsp.products_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 148 in the jsp file: /products.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
method processRequest in class jdbc.units cannot be applied to given types;
required: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Here is my code..

**units.java**

```
package jdbc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import org.json.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class units extends HttpServlet {
     protected ResultSet processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(units.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gst_application", "root", "");
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM `product_units` ORDER BY `product_unit_id` ASC";
                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(units.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                out.print(ex);
            }

        }
        return rs;
    }
}
```

**product.jsp**

```
<%@page import="jdbc.units"%>
<select class="form-control" name="product_unit" required="required">
    <%
        units obj = new units();
        ResultSet rs = obj.processRequest();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            out.print("<option>"+rs.getString("unit_val")+"</option>"); 
        }
    %>
 </select>
```

Comment: You should never, ever pass a ResultSet out of the method that creates it.  You need to map the values into an object or data structure and close the ResultSet in method scope in a finally block.  Do not write scriptlet code in JSPs.  If you must write a JSP, you should only use JSTL.

Answer (score 1):

First a warning: You should not use ResultSet in your page directly. You should put the result in an intermediate object and then close ResultSet, Statement and if required the connection.

That being said, as far as I see you are missing import statement in your JSP page so JSP compiler cannot find the ResultSet class. Try importing jdbc packages in your JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `ResultSet` object in a List and pass it to your page and in JSP extract this list. Here I am assuming `Demo` is your class name. Uou can change code based on your class name. And do not forget to close the connections.

**In Servlet**

```
Demo d = null;
List <Demo> myList = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
        myList.add(d);
}
rs.close();
ps.close();
con.close();
request.setAttribute("List", myList);
```

Forward your response to the JSP file like this:

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pageName.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

**In JSP**

use this tag:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Access the list using `forEach`

```
<c:forEach items="${List}" var="theList">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>${theList.attributeName}</td>
                ...
            </tr>
</c:forEach>
```